# sendgrid send multiple receipts email

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, email, sendgrid

hello all i am having problem in sendgrid's send multiple receipt email api problem 
actually the api accepts this array

```
<?php

  $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
    $user = 'abc';
    $pass = 'xyx';
  $params = array(
'api_user'  => $user,
'api_key'   => $pass,
'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($json_string),
'to'        => "$to",
'subject'   => "$subject",
'html'      => "$messaget",
'from'      => "site.com<contact@site.com>",
 );


  $request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

 // Generate curl request
   $session = curl_init($request);
    // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
  curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
  // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
      curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    // Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
     curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

     // obtain response
       $response = curl_exec($session);
      curl_close($session);
          ?>
```

the problem is here

```
 $json_string = array(
'to' => array(
"$emailfinallist"
  ),
 'category' => 'test_category'
);
```

when i keep the json_string  as like

```
 $json_string = array(
'to' => array(
'email1','email2'
  ),
 'category' => 'test_category'
);
```

it sends but the problem is that i am getting the emails from my database by mysql how do i put the emails directly into the array i am using a loop and
storing the fetched emails into a variable $emailfinallist and passing this variable to the $json_string  array but that dosent works ....

how do i put the emails directly into this array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're passing a string, not a variable in the 'to' param:

`'to' => array("$emailfinallist")`
should be
`'to' => $emailfinallist`

You're also doing the same thing for the 'subject' and 'html' params.